# Pandas groupby datatime index, possible bug

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column that is a tz-aware TimeStamp and I tried to groupby(level=0).first(). I get an incorrect result. Am I missing something or is it a pandas bug?

```
x = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,1,2,2,2], data = pd.date_range("7:00", "9:00", freq="30min", tz = 'US/Eastern'))

In [58]: x
Out[58]: 


     0
1 2016-09-08 07:00:00-04:00
1 2016-09-08 07:30:00-04:00
2 2016-09-08 08:00:00-04:00
2 2016-09-08 08:30:00-04:00
2 2016-09-08 09:00:00-04:00

In [59]: x.groupby(level=0).first()
Out[59]: 
                          0
1 2016-09-08 11:00:00-04:00
2 2016-09-08 12:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: It looks like a bug... Pandas converted timestamps into UTC, but it also preserved old TZ info...

Comment: Definitely a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that it is a bug. If you go through the [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) docs, it is clearly indicated that for timezone US/Eastern, there is no way to specify before / after the end-of-daylight-saving-time transition.

In such cases, sticking with UTC seems to be the best option.

Excerpt from the [`docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#caveats):

> ```
>  Be aware that timezones (e.g., pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')) are not
>  necessarily equal across timezone versions. So if data is localized to
>  a specific timezone in the HDFStore using one version of a timezone
>  library and that data is updated with another version, the data will
>  be converted to UTC since these timezones are not considered equal.
>  Either use the same version of timezone library or use tz_convert with
>  the updated timezone definition.
> ```

The conversion can be done as follows:

**A:** using `tz_localize` method to localize naive/time-aware datetime to UTC

```
data = pd.date_range("7:00", "9:00", freq="30min").tz_localize('UTC')
```

**B:** using `tz_convert` method to convert pandas objects to convert 
tz aware data to another time zone.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,1,2,2,2], data=data.tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

which results in:

```
                          0
1 2016-09-09 07:00:00-04:00
2 2016-09-09 08:00:00-04:00

#0    datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pandas bug reported here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10668